# Where to put model related logic in Django project that is not instance related

Tags: python, django, business-logic

I have a code snippet to pick the last date in a table and then perform some logic to get a new date. Where should this logic be put in a django project? I have seen examples of Fat Models where the logic is put as a method to the model but this works only on an instance as far as I can tell.

```
# models.py
class PurchasesDetails(models.Model):
    purchaseid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    effectivedate = models.DateField()

    def getselecteddate(self):
        lastdate = PurchasesDetails.objects.filter().aggregate(Max('effectivedate'))
        lastdate = next (iter (lastdate.values()))
        thisweekday = lastdate.weekday()
        advancedays = 1
        if thisweekday ==4:
            advancedays = 3
        thisdate = (lastdate + timedelta(days=advancedays))

        return thisdate
```

Comment: maybe in a [model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/)?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#model-methods), a `model manager` looks like the best place where to define such logic

> Define custom methods on a model to add custom “row-level”
>   functionality to your objects. Whereas Manager methods are intended to
>   do “table-wide” things, model methods should act on a particular model
>   instance.
>
> This is a valuable technique for keeping business logic in one place –
>   the model.

So, for example, in your case

```
class _DetailsManager(models.Manager):

    def getselecteddate(self):
        lastdate = PurchasesDetails.objects.filter().aggregate(Max('effectivedate'))
        lastdate = next (iter (lastdate.values()))
        thisweekday = lastdate.weekday()
        advancedays = 1
        if thisweekday == 4:
            advancedays = 3
        thisdate = (lastdate + timedelta(days=advancedays))

        return thisdate

class PurchasesDetails(models.Model):
    purchaseid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    effectivedate = models.DateField()
    objects = _DetailsManager()

new_date = PurchasesDetails.objects.getselecteddate()
```

Please read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Manager) the specific documentation dedicated to customizing model managers.

Comment: Thank you Pynchia. Should class _DetailsManager(models.Model) be class _DetailsManager(models.Manager)? Also I am getting an error that _DetailsManager is undefined when I refer to it in the model itself

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, I was shooting out of my home and I did not finish editing fully. Regarding the `undefined` it''s really weird, it works in my code. If you think my answer solves your problem correctly and better than others', please mark it as accepted. Thank you.